# How do I replace a word with regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex

How can I replace a word with a regex (regular expression) in C#?

Example:

```
string _test = "Test2 Test Test() Function(Test)";
_test = Regex.Replace(_test, regexVariable, "Boat");
```

Would result in `_test` having the value `"Test2 Boat Boat() Function(Boat)"`

Answer (score 2):

See documentation for the [word boundary character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary), `\b`.

```
Regex.Replace("Test2 Test Test() Function(Test)", @"\bTest\b", "Boat")
```

Output:

```
Test2 Boat Boat() Function(Boat)
```